# Can you please identify these trees?

Tags: identification, trees

Could you identify these two trees please? I live in Western Australia if that helps. I believe the first one is a blood Gum.

[image: Tree one - Blood Gum?]
[image: Tree one - Leaf Detail]

My dog likes chewing the lower branches of this second one, so really want to make sure that's not a problem.

[image: Tree two]

Thanks!

Comment: It does resemble https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corymbia_ficifolia but I'm not totally convinced.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure this is an eucalyptus. For being 100% sure :

- Bark is constently peeling in thin shred,
- Leaves have a strong (and pleasant) smell

As you suggested, the red flowers suggest a **corymbia ficifolia**.